# OCI runtime execution failed

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Getting this error when i ran ./byfn.sh -m up command : OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"scripts/script.sh\": stat scripts/script.sh: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing part of the byfn.sh script. Have you cloned the Hyperledger examples? There should be a directory called scripts containing script.sh and utils.sh. Byfn is dependent on both scripts

Comment: Thanks Moriarty, Now i'm facing this problem "ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto" Any suggestion on this will be a great help

Comment: Np, can I get an answer and upvote? As for he second problem, can you post more of the error? And the commands to replicate error? Thanks

Comment: when i triggered ./byfn -m generate and  ./byfn -m up i get the error "Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing ....crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp"

Comment: byfn is a shell script that runs all the Hyperledger binaries to setup a local blockchain network, if you follow the step by step instructions in the first network tutorial you can isolate the error more precisely. Also had you run ./byfn generate first?